# Why are both these function pointers legal in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, return, function-pointers

I have these two test functions:

```
int apply_a(int (*fun)(int, int), int m, int n) {
    return (*fun)(m,n);
}

int apply_b(int (*fun)(int, int), int m, int n) {
    return fun(m,n);
}
```

they appear to return something different, so why do both of them yield the same result?

```
int add(int a, int b) {return a + b;}

int res_a = apply_a(add, 2, 3); // returns 5
int res_b = apply_b(add, 2, 3); // returns 5
```

I would've assumed that one of them would return the pointer address or the pointer itself; rather than the value stored on the pointer...

So why is it doing this?

Comment: Because either syntax (with or without the asterisk) is valid for calling a function through a pointer. The second case is a call (you can tell by the parentheses and passed parameters).

Comment: Neither is good. You should use `(***fun)(m, n)` to qualify as a three-star programmer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because C++ offers syntactic sugar when it comes to handling the address of non-member functions and using pointers to them.

One can get address of such function:

```
int someFunc(int);
```

with either:

```
int (* someFuncPtr)(int) = someFunc;
```

or:

```
int (* someFuncPtr)(int) = &someFunc;
```

There is also syntactic sugar for using such pointer, either call pointed-to function with:

```
(*someFuncPtr)(5);
```

or with simplified syntax:

```
someFuncPtr(5);
```

Comment: Remember that the same applies also to static class methods (at least on Visual C++ 2012 where I've checked ;))

Comment: does this apply in C too? or is the sugar rule only for C++?

Comment: C++ introduces another notation for "function" type: `int(int)` which is convertible to `int(*)(int)`. `someFunc` has type `int(int)` whereas `&someFunc` has type `int(*)(int)`.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee, it applies to C too.

Answer (score 6):

`(*fun)(m,n)` is the same as `fun(m,n)` due to rules in C and C++ that convert functions to pointers to functions.

In C 2011, the rule is clause 6.3.2.1 4: “A *function designator* is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the **sizeof** operator, the **_Alignof operator**, or the unary **&** operator, a function designator with type “function returning *type*” is converted to an expression that has type “pointer to function returning *type*”. In C++, the rule is clause 4.3.

Note that a *function designator* is not merely an identifier that names a function. It could be an identifier, or it could be another expression. For example, if `foo` is the name of a function, it is automatically converted to a pointer to a function by the above. Then, since `foo` is a pointer to the function, `*foo` is the function. This means you can write:

```
(*fun)(m,n)
```

The result is that `fun` is automatically converted to a pointer, then `*` evaluates to the function, then `*fun` is converted back to a pointer, then the function is called. You can continue this and write:

```
(**************fun)(m,n)
```

This is the same as `fun(m,n)`. Each `*` produces the function again, but the compiler automatically converts it back to a pointer. You can continue this battle forever, but the compiler will always win.

In fact, these all have the same effect:

```
(&fun)(m,n)
( fun)(m,n)
(*fun)(m,n)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not returning memory addresses of these values.
Calling a function with pointer does not change it's value it's still calling the function. What you can do is return a value to a variable and then get it's memory address such as:

```
int result = fun(m,n);
cout << "the result " << result << " pointing at " << &result << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++ name of functions are also the pointers to the function code. As any pointer you can dereference them using `*`, which in case of function pointers mean invocation of the function when in addition to dereferencing you use also paranthesis after them, like in your `apply_a` case. But also valid invocation of C and C++ function is calling them simply by their name, which is `apply_b` case.

Comment: It is not the name. **Any** expression that is a function, not just a function name, will be converted to a pointer to the function.